# Intent with multiple startactivity paramaters

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I want a value to be passed from the first to the last activity when a button is clicked.

At the same time I want this button to bring me to the second activity. Somehow this doesn't work.

```
private void imagebutton1 () {
          ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  //startActivity (new Intent(Akt1.this,Akt2.class));

                  String data1 = "data1";

                  Intent intent = new Intent (Akt1.this,Akt2.class);
                  Intent passdata_intent = new Intent(Akt1.this, Akt6.class);
                  passdata_intent.putExtra("data1",data1);

                 startActivity(passdata_intent);

              }
          });
```

Comment: Currently, you aren't doing anything with the "intent" Intent. What you are trying to achieve is quite unclear for me right now, could you explain more ?

Comment: when this button is pressed, i want the next activity to open and at the same time a value to be passed to my last activity " Akt6"

Comment: Then I suggest you use SharedPreferences instead of an Extra, as said in some answers, you can't put an extra to an activity you're not going onto. You should save your value to prefs and to go to AKT2, then when you get to the AKT6, get it. **See my answer**

Comment: okay i tried it with sharedpreferences now but have a new problem. How can i do it that a value is only shown when the button is pressed? Right now it shows the same value whatever button i press

Comment: your method only listens to the "ImageButton4" if you want each ImageButton to send a different value, you'll have to set a listener to each of them.

Answer (score 0):

> i want a value to be passed from the first to the last activity when a
>   button is clicked.

Sorry, it is impossible. You have to follow the activity stack.

To pass data from one to another, one `intent` had enough, no need to have two.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent (Akt1.this,Akt2.class);
 intent.putExtra("data1",data1);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Refer from [how to directly pass value of a variable from 1st activty to 3rd activity using putextra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178793/how-to-directly-pass-value-of-a-variable-from-1st-activty-to-3rd-activity-using)

---

**Akt1**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent (Akt1.this,Akt2.class);
 intent.putExtra("data1",data1);
 startActivity(intent);
```

**Akt2**

After `setContentView`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data1 = intent.getStringExtra("data1");
```

Comment: It has to be somehow possible that a value from the first activity is passed to the last one, so that i can make a calculation at the very end of the app :( maybe i used a wrong method?

Comment: How your activity flow looked like? You can pass it from Activity one to two, then in activity two pass to three...until the last activity

Comment: i thought about this too but how exactly do i do this? because i dont want the value to be shown in every activity. only in the last one. so how do i pass it through the others, without showing it?

Comment: You can pass it without showing it. You can also save the data to database, in last activity, retrieve it. Easy

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Where you call the last activity ? In which activity ?

Comment: i call the last activity " Akt6" in the second last " Akt5". But i pass a value to Akt6 from my first activity.

Comment: then in Akt2 will it called Akt3 and so on  ?

Comment: basically in every Akt i have button that pass a value to Akt6 and open the next Akt. It is an app that makes a calculation in the end with the values

Answer (score 0):

```
private void imagebutton1 () {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                String data1 = "data1";

                Intent intent = new Intent (Akt1.this,Akt2.class);
                intent.putExtra("data1",data1);

               startActivity(intent );

            }
        });
```

For example :

In MainActivity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(OtherActivity.KEY_EXTRA, yourDataObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

In OtherActivity :

```
public static final String KEY_EXTRA = "com.example.yourapp.KEY_BOOK";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  String yourDataObject = null;

  if (getIntent().hasExtra(KEY_EXTRA)) {
      yourDataObject = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_EXTRA);
  } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity cannot find  extras " + KEY_EXTRA);
  }
  // do stuff
}
```

More informations here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you need to start two activies with one button, but you can start first activity and in your first activity's on create you can start second activity (you can recreate your intent in first activity.)

Comment: i have two buttons on my very first activity  .. one button for "male" and one for "female" . Now regardless of what button is pressed, the next activity to be opened, is activity2. At the same time if e.g. the user pressed "male", then i want the variable " male" to be saved on my last activity of the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //startActivity (new Intent(Akt1.this,Akt2.class));

                String data1 = "data1";

                Intent intent = new Intent (Akt1.this,Akt2.class);
                intent.putExtra("data1",data1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

In your Akt2.class add this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    String data1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data1");

    // your code

}
```

Comment: i dont quite get this. on the first one why startActivity(passdata_intent) ?

Comment: did you try this

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following :**

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //startActivity (new Intent(Akt1.this,Akt2.class));

                String data1 = "data1";

                getSharedPreferences("YOURKEY", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("someKey", data1).apply();

                startActivity(new Intent (Akt1.this, Akt2.class));
            }
```

**Then in AKT6 :**

```
String data1 = getSharedPreferences("YOURKEY", MODE_PRIVATE).prefs.getString("someKey");
```